# MongoDB Read-only view field Masking

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB, and trying to see a way where we can mask fields for privacy. Tried Read-only view in MongoDB 3.4

I have below collection,

```
db.employees.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59802d45d2f4250001ead835"),
        "name" : "Nick",
        "mobile" : "927 113 4566"
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59802d45d2f4250001ead835"),
        "name" : "Sam",
        "mobile" : "817 133 4566"
}
```

**Created a Read-only view:**

```
db.createView("employeeView", "employees", [ {$project : { "mobile": 1} } ] )

db.employeeView.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59802d45d2f4250001ead835"), "mobile" : "927 113 4566"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59802d45d2f4250001ead835"), "mobile" : "817 133 4566"}
```

but I am not finding a solution to mask 'mobile' field in employeeView, but it is mentioned that we can able to mask in MongoDB GDPR white paper

https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/gdpr-impact-to-your-data-management-landscape

Any suggestion to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to "mask" the `mobile` field value, depending on your use case. Views are constructed based upon [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), and you could utilise it according to your needs.

An example, you can simply use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to hide the `mobile` field. 
i.e. given these documents:

```
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Nick", "mobile": "927 113 4566"}
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Sam", "mobile": "817 133 4566"}
```

You could exclude the `mobile` field in the view:

```
> db.createView("empView", "employees", [{"$project":{name:1}}])
> db.empView.find() 
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Nick"}
{"_id": ObjectId(".."),"name": "Sam"}
```

Or perhaps you have an extra field in your document to indicate whether the information is public or not, i.e. given documents:

```
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Nick", "mobile": "927 113 4566", "show": true}
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Sam", "mobile": "817 133 4566", "show": false}
```

You could utilise [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expression to mask based on field `show`. For example:

```
> db.createView("empView", "employees", 
             [{$project:{ 
               name:1, 
               mobile:{$cond:{
                       if:{$eq:["$show", false]}, 
                       then: "xxx xxx xxxx", 
                       else: "$mobile"}}
}}])

> db.empView.find() 

{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Nick", "mobile": "927 113 4566"}
{"_id": ObjectId(".."), "name": "Sam", "mobile": "xxx xxx xxxx"}
```